# How To Implement Multi Layered Architecture in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, architecture, soa

I have identified below layers to be implemented in my application. According to my knowledge multi layered architecture is prefered for an enterprise application.

- Presentation Layer
- Business Layer
- Data Access Layer
- Service Layer

I have chosen Symfony2 as the framework to be used in the app. Symfony2 has MVC architecture built into it. And the above layers exist as below.

- Presentation Layer => Controller & Views
- Business Layer, Service Layer => Model
- Data Access Layer => Also Model but Doctrine is used.

Model is consisted with Business Layer, Data Access Layer, Service Layer. See the below image that is [borrowed from Martin Fowler's book, *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).

[image: Diagram of service layer, with concentric circles]

My problem is,

is there a way to decouple the model into separate  Business Layer, Data Access Layer, Service Layer ? How to implement multi Layered architecture in PHP ? Should I use some other framework(If only it supports layered architecture) ?

## Update

Below link was helpful

[How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/)

[How to build n-layered web architecture with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539522/how-to-build-n-layered-web-architecture-with-php)

[What is difference of developing a website in MVC and 3-Tier or N-tier architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843311/what-is-difference-of-developing-a-website-in-mvc-and-3-tier-or-n-tier-architect)

[MVC application. How does mult-tier architecture fit in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135056/mvc-application-how-does-mult-tier-architecture-fit-in)

[Implementing a service layer in an MVC architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352063/implementing-a-service-layer-in-an-mvc-architecture)

[Achieving 3-tier architecture with Symfony PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484458/achieving-3-tier-architecture-with-symfony-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> <sub>If you are serious about even trying to make something MVC-inspired, then your only options are Synfony and Zend. The others are just sad Rails-clones, that implement some bastardization of [PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control). And Sf2.x seems to better one of two .. but that's like pointing out smartest kid in the remedial class.
>
>   Unless you are able and willing to make your own framework, Sf2.x will be your best bet.</sub>

I think the main problem here is the misunderstanding what "model" in MVC is. Model is a layer, not any specific class or object. In the picture from Fowler's book, the "**MVC model**" will be all three concentric circles taken together.

You basically have two major layer in MVC: model layer and presentation layer. The presentation layer interacts with model layer through services, that let you abstract the underlaying domain business logic.

Do not confuse it with "**domain model**". Domain model is an idea that describes all the knowledge and expertise from client's business, that is used in creation of application. Usually it will be represented as separate [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and the interaction of said objects.

Also, this picture is somewhat misleading. The data abstraction layer (usually implemented as collection of [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)) is not lower level structure then domain model. Both domain objects and storage abstractions are uses by service (either directly or through repositories & units of work). It is referred to as "application logic" and is a direct responsibility of services.

Bottom line: no, you do not need to pick some different framework. You only need to learn more about application architecture. You should read [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) .. that would be a good place to start.

<kbd>My 2 cents</kbd>

Comment: It is a common courtesy to explain reason for downvote. What's exactly wrong with this answer?