# How can I implement layered architecture in a PHP framework with design patterns?

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, design-patterns, laravel

As you know other than [GOF](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GangOfFour), there are design patterns for each layer which should be used in coding. Each layer has separate design patterns. Please the picture below.

[image]

I have identified below layers to be implemented.

```
 Presentation Layer
        |
        v
  Service Layer
        |
        v
  Business Layer
        |
        v
Data Access Layer
        |
        v
 Persistence Layer
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743338/how-to-implement-multi-layered-architecture-in-php) questions but it does not provide a answer how to implement them in a framework.

**How can I implement layered architecture in a PHP *framework* with design patterns?**

*Frameworks interested in laravel, symfony, zend*

Comment: Are you saying that you want to build something similar to .NET MVC for PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the Model View Controller framework.  I use it occasionally instead of MVP (Model View Presenter).

There is a similar framework for PHP here: http://simplemvcframework.com/.  I have not used it so I do not know how good it is.

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288041.aspx.  Whilst this is for .NET Developers; the patterns still apply to PHP development.  I was not the down voter.